# How to add one specific page (PDF file) to a list of existing PDF files?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have 400 different pdf files in one folder and need to add one specific page (1 other pdf file, page.pdf) automatically to all of these 400 files, always at the end.

How can I do that?

Comment: You might explain the reason, `pdftk` isn't an acceptable solution, looking at most questions on how to process a batch of PDFs it seems those asking this type of question actually use `pdftk`.

Comment: This extra page is in which format? PDF as well? Also, which OS?

Comment: I found the answer. It is:

Comment: for %a in (inputfiles*.pdf) do @pdftk "%~a" onepage.pdf cat output "Added %~na %~xa"

Comment: Please read [Can I answer my own question?](http://superuser/help/self-answer)

Comment: You can answer your own questions. Can you put that in an answer, then tick it.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you are running some sort of Unix system (these days, anything but Microsoft's windows).

Then install `pdfjoin` (it is part of pdfjam package)

and do this

```
find . -iname "*.pdf" -print0 | xargs -0 -i{} echo pdfjoin --outfile output.pdf {} backpage.pdf
```